# Detect if there are to more pages to use $.post using jQuery

Tags: jquery, post, infinite-scroll

Im trying to implement an infinite scrolling feature in a website. Theres a div '#books' with multiple divs '.book' in it. So far this is working fine:

```
alreadyloading = false;
nextpage = 1;

$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($('body').height() <= ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop())) {
    if (alreadyloading == false) {
        var url = "page"+nextpage+".html";
        alreadyloading = true;
        $('#books').append($('#loadinggif').fadeIn(200));
        $.post(url, function(data) {
            $('#books').append(data);
            alreadyloading = false;
            nextpage++;
            $('#loadinggif').fadeOut(200);
        });
    }
}
});
```

However, the #lodinggif stays at the bottom even after all content is loaded. Any way I can
detect that pagex.html doesnt exist and then hide #loadinggif ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read the docs for [jQuery.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/), it says this about the callback:

> **success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)**
>   A callback function that is executed if the request succeeds.

So you can't catch error conditions with `$.post`. But you can catch them by using the long-form [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) instead of the post shorthand:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        $('#books').append(data);
        nextpage++;
        alreadyloading = false;
        $('#loadinggif').fadeOut(200);
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alreadyloading = false;
        $('#loadinggif').fadeOut(200);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The server will need to provide this information in addition to the data. So you could let the server return an XML or JSON file with the data and whether the next page actually exists.